# monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 100 Returns Unsuccessful --

Tags: monerod, error-log

What am I doing wrong? ( Ubuntu 16.04 )

```
monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod --version
Creating the logger system
Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.1.0-dd580d7)
monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod print_status
Creating the logger system
monerod is running
monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 10
Creating the logger system
Error: Unsuccessful --
monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 1000
Creating the logger system
Error: Unsuccessful --
monero@monerod:/opt/monero/bin$ sudo ./monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 1 1000
Creating the logger system
Error: Unsuccessful --
```

I recompiled with the "Bleeding Edge" code. Getting more errors now!

```
monero@monerod:/tmp/monero/build/release/bin$ sudo /opt/monero/bin/monerod print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 10

2017-02-13 11:02:08.327 7f4fabc51740 INFO global contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145 New log categories: :WARNING,net:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO

2017-02-13 11:02:08.329 7f4fabc51740 ERROR msgwriter src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:94 Error: Unsuccessful --

Error: Unsuccessful --
```

Version: Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.1.0-3f171b9)
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: It also does it with Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.1.0-release)

Comment: For reference: [github issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1722).

Comment: yah that's my github question..

Comment: It looks like it was fixed, however I haven't tested it

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1722

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, this was [fixed](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1729) some time ago.

```
print_coinbase_tx_sum 0 100
INFO  [default] Page size: 4096
Sum of coinbase transactions between block heights [0, 100) is 1759.135559809471 consisting of 1759.135559809471 in emissions, and 0.000000000000 in fees
```